# How do I force reload of PHP page when pressing back and forward buttons on the browser?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get a PHP application to reload on page back or page forward on Firefox, Internet Explorer browsers.

I have formulated the code below that is partially working on some pages in other words when I navigate back and forward I do get a page reload instead of `Document Expired` or a cached page.  Other pages do not successfully reload the page contents on back or forward button press, and instead give the common message `Document Expired` indicating that my method did not succeed on those pages.

**Session.php - Included on top of all php scripts and primarily handles load of page on request for reloads**

```
 <?php
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['page_requested'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 


        if (isset($_POST['scrollamount']) && $_POST['scrollamount'] != "")
                $_SESSION['scrollamount'] = $_POST['scrollamount'];


        if (isset($_SESSION['page_loaded']) && !isset($_GET['load']))
        {
            unset($_SESSION['page_loaded']);
            if (strpos($_SESSION['page_requested'], '?') !== false)
            {
                header("Location: $_SESSION[page_requested]&load=1");
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: $_SESSION[page_requested]?load=1");
                exit;
            }       
        }
        else if (!isset($_GET['load']))
        {
          header("Location: ?load=1");
          exit;  
        }
    ?>
```

**reload.php - This clears the get value so that a redirect loop is not encountered and this script is included after the one above and on each php script**

```
<?
        $_SESSION['page_loaded'] = true;
        $_SESSION['page_requested'] = str_replace('&load=1', '', $_SESSION['page_requested']);
        $_SESSION['page_requested'] = str_replace('?load=1', '', $_SESSION['page_requested']);
?>
```

On every PHP page with an  tag I have modified the contents to of the tag to be `<body onunload="">` to try to force reload following some insightful suggestions.

Unfortunately the reload behavior is not working consistently and reliably.

**How can I modify what I have so far to work across all PHP scripts?**

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

When you the user presses "Back" the browser knows that the previous page was submitted via POST and asks the user if he wants to resubmit the form BEFORE loading anything. So you can't add anything that would trigger the reload, neither via server side or via client side scripting, because the browser doesn't even load it before it prompts the user.

The only way to prevent this is to switch from POST to GET (which has other drawbacks, of course). Alternatively you can use AJAX for all POST forms and redirect to the next page after the result came in.